# error in executing query

Tags: xml, xquery

```
<query1><abc>76</abc><abc>20</abc><abc>30</abc></query1>
```

I am getting this output after executing the xquery.What I need is That I want to count the numbers -76+20+30. I want the sum as the output. But it is giving me the above line as ouput.

I just used the "for" expression and then return the result.How do I get the result.
I tried using sum{$e} in the return but, it is still producing me the same output. I need the total of these numbers.

```
  for $r in (doc("yahoo.xml")/vid/number)
    return
    <abc>{$r}</abc>
```

I am gettingthe above output. I should get the total of it.

Comment: If you don't post your xquery source code, how are we supposed to figure out what you did and why it's wrong?

Comment: why do the begin and end tags not match? <query1>...</query2>

Comment: @eric...that was by mistake..its same...I wrote it wrong

Comment: please check the upated question.....

Answer (score 0):

With this input (properly wellformed)

```
<query1>
    <abc>76</abc>
    <abc>20</abc>
    <abc>30</abc>
</query1>
```

Even this XPath 1.0 will work.

```
sum(/query1/abc)
```

You are getting what you have declared you want: *for each `number` element (as $r) return an `abc` element with $r as child*. In fact your output should look like:

```
    <abc><number>76</number></abc>
    <abc><number>20</number></abc>
    <abc><number>30</number></abc>
```

You should use:

```
element abc {sum(doc("yahoo.xml")/vid/number)}
```

Comment: actually , I have multiple elements. its just adding the contents of a single element. But the other elements are not included in the total

Comment: like...its just adding 76+20 but 30 is not badded in the total

Comment: @user507087: Then your are selecting the wrong nodes. Post a better input source sample.

Comment: @Alejandro....Can I email you my data file....i just showed you the eg by ctting the unwanted material.If you say, I can email you my data file.Plz..try to understand my problem.

Comment: @user507087: You can use this site http://xmltools.dk/ Then you can test or even post here the permalink.

Comment: it is not working for some time.It is mentioned on the website.My email id is shib.shilpa@gmail.com....

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from the question, so I'm going to guess as to what your XML input looks like and what you are trying to get as output.

**XML Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vid>
  <number>76</number>
  <number>20</number>
  <number>30</number>
</vid>
```

**XQuery**

```
for $r in (doc("yahoo.xml")/vid)
    let $total := sum($r/number)
    return
    <query1>
      <abc>{$total}</abc>
    </query1>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query1>
   <abc>126</abc>
</query1>
```

Comment: I have multiple elements . Its jus adding the contents of single element.Like here, 76+20 only is happening, not adding the 30.

Comment: ??? In my example, all 3 `number` s are getting added. Without supplying us with the input XML (or a working example), everything is going to be a guess.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. Use:

```
<abc>{sum(doc("yahoo.xml")/vid/number)}</abc>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I consider the xml as follows, we need to take the node and add it.

```
   let $query := <query1>
                    <abc>76</abc>
                    <abc>20</abc>
                    <abc>30</abc>
                  </query1>

    let $sum := for $r in ($query)
                let $total := sum($r/node())
                return <query1>
                        <abc>{$total}</abc>
                       </query1>
    return $sum
```